# How can I use a CDI portable extension to add a qualifier to a session bean that captures its EJB name?

Tags: ejb, cdi

The big picture: I would ultimately like the ability, given just an EJB name, to be able to look up a business interface view of that EJB, in an `.ear` file, without knowing its module name—regardless, in other words, of what `.jar` file it might be packaged in, or what `module-name` it might have been given in a deployment descriptor somewhere.  (Currently, `java:app` JNDI names require you to know what EJB module the EJB name is relative to; this is a non-starter for me.)

With portable JNDI names not solving my problem, I turned to CDI.

It seems to me that if I can Get To A Place Where I can ask a `BeanManager` for a CDI bean of a particular type **and with a particular name** (no, I can't use `@Named` for this; I don't control the authoring of the EJBs in question), then I can effectively get what I want, provided that all such beans are obviously deployed in bean archives.  Fine.

To get *here*, I can use a CDI portable extension to observe the container's lifecycle.  I get that.

There are two interesting events, then, that I wish to observe, and I'm interested in what I can change, when, during observation.  One is `ProcessAnnotatedType` and the other is `ProcessSessionBean`.

The catch is that during `ProcessAnnotatedType` I'd like to add a home-grown annotation (`EJBNamed` or some such; haven't written it yet) that captures the EJB's "official" `ejb-name`.  This name of course can come from at least three different metadata sources with the EJB and Java EE 6 specifications dictating exactly which overrides what.  But at `ProcessAnnotatedType`-time, that information is not yet available.

During `ProcessSessionBean`, I can of course get the bean name, but it is my understanding that by that point it is too late—since my `ProcessAnnotatedType` phase already went by, it seems that my chance at modifying things has come and gone.

First, is that correct?  Suppose at `ProcessAnnotatedType` time I decorate the `AnnotatedType` with a qualifier of my own that is mutable.  Suppose further, then, at `ProcessSessionBean` time I get that annotated type and add my `@EJBNamed` annotation.

It seems to me this should be legal, as long as I don't expect the container to actually *do* anything with that annotation, which I don't.  I *do* expect to be able—later—to ask for a `Bean` with that qualifier of a given type.

So: is it possible for subsequent CDI portable extension observer methods to muck with annotations and such installed during previous portable extension observer method executions?

Comment: I guess why is it mandatory to do this using `@EJBNamed`?  I think it would be more appropriate to register the list of names in a `HashMap` and make that accessible, based on `interface` and `ejbName`?  But more importantly why can't you just `@Inject` the business interface?

Comment: For a variety of legacy and dumb reasons the interface name and the EJB name are being supplied at runtime.  If all I have is the interface name and bean name, then I cannot use Java EE's JNDI syntax to resolve them to a deployed EJB, because I must also know the EJB's module name, which I do not.  I was hoping that CDI could help me here.